# ADSL connection problem - Internet pages keep loading and loading

Tags: internet-connection, adsl

My network operator did some changes in my building, related to enabling VDSL2 technology. They sent us a letter telling that this change does not have any impact of our ADSL connections. Infact this is only good, because if we want, we can order even higher Internet connection. After the change was done, my ADSL didn't work well anymore, but the operator keeps saying that there is nothing wrong with my connection.

I have tried with 2 different ADSL2+ capable ADSL modems. I have tried different lines to connect with. Network operator says I should try even third ADSL modem, which is in my opinion nonsense, because both of the modems worked well before the change was done.

Some symptoms:

```
- When I start loading any webpage, the browser keeps showing still-loading animation forever.
- Some webpages render open fine although animation is still running.
- Loading some bigfile, for example debian image, download is fine and doesn't get interrupted, although the download speed could be higher.
- Login to gmail is practically impossible.
- Some webpages open if you keep hitting refresh. The rule: if it doesn't open in a second, it never opens.
- These problems are common across 3 different computers, 3 different webbrowsers and on Linux and Windows.
```

Any ideas what is wrong and how can I tell the network operator that it's not my fault?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar problem with a ADSL2+ subscription. In the end I changed the DNS server from my ISP's automatic one to Googles free DNS servers. The IP's are:

```
8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
```

There is more information here: http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/

Not only did fix the problem, it is faster than my ISP's DNS server.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

So, ISP provider gave you those modems or you get it yourself?
Did you try to login to the modem from computer using web interface?

Comment: If I want VDSL modem, I should buy it myself. Another of the ADSL modems is my own and the other belongs to the rental flat. Don't know if the latter is from ISP.

Comment: Did you try to login to the modem from computer using web interface?
you should see system status. Did you try other DNS as AkkA said?